# Accessing Page Public Content - App Review Required, but why?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I started to work at a company and I was given the task to use graph API to get a given sites public posts and its reactions and make statistics saved to a database, using nothing personal, only the things everyone can see. I need Public Page Content Access to do so but I must submit it for review which I can't because I need a feature for it which I can't develop because I need PPCA and so on...

However ( if I understood it correctly ) it was written if "My app" has someone who has the role of admin on that given page and is tester/developer/administrator then I can freely access that pages content without submitting. And this parameter checks, but the graph request still gives me this error:

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/page-id-with-admin-in-app-project-as-admin-too/feed?access_token=access-token

(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review."](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.%22)

Did I miss something? Or should it be submitted anyways?

Comment: Works fine for me, as long as the app is in dev mode.

Comment: My app is in dev mode too. Did you try it with a page you are admin in or with a page which's admin is in your project as a [insert role here] ?

Comment: Both admin of the app and the page. Does your token include manage_pages permission?

Comment: Yes, it does have.

Comment: Go check if `/me/accounts` lists the page in question. If not, try and remove manage_pages permission, and grant it again.

Comment: Did not work... But I was "promoted" to admin on the page for test purposes and it did the trick. It is not a perfect solution for us tho...

Comment: Well then you need to submit and get this feature approved …